# Error while trying to resize a disk partition

Tags: ubuntu, partition, disk, oracle-vm-server

Im trying to resize a disk partition in Ubuntu 22.04 in OracleVM. I already resize the disk in the VM software but in Ubuntu the disk still with the old size. I think it resize but in a new partition and I can't use that partition. When trying to change the disk size in the Ubuntu disk management this error pops out:

[image]

Any solution? I need to be able to use the disk.

Comment: Maybe you'll need to move the backup GPT to the new end of the disk first (with e.g. `gdisk`).

Comment: Wait did you make the disk larger or smaller? (Please please please tell us you made it larger)